# How to remove the top and bottom padding of UIButton, when create it using auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, autolayout, padding

When create UIButton with auto layout, the `intrinsicContentSize` always contain different top/bottom padding according to different text font size. I try to set `contentEdgeInsets`, but it not really works for top/bottom padding.

How to fix the padding to 0 or any constant value?

Answer (score 51):

After some experimentation, it appears that if you try and set `contentEdgeInsets` to all zeros, the default insets are used. However, if you set them to *nearly* zero, it works:

```
button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0.01, bottom: 0.01, right: 0)
```

It also appears that the values get `floor`'d, so you won't actually get fractional padding.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: The weird thing is that it transforms back to `0` in `Interface Builder`, thought it correctly sets to `0.01` in the `.xib`/`.storyboard` file.

Answer (score 11):

**Updated for Swift 5**

If you are wanting the button to size to its titleLabel's contents, I found that the only way to do so is by subclassing UIButton and overriding intrinsicContentSize. Hope this works for you!

```swift
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? super.intrinsicContentSize
    }
}
```

If you need to use `titleEdgeInsets`, you can update your UIButton subclass like this:

```swift
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override var titleEdgeInsets: UIEdgeInsets {
        didSet {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var sizeWithInsets = titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? super.intrinsicContentSize
        sizeWithInsets.width += titleEdgeInsets.left + titleEdgeInsets.right
        sizeWithInsets.height += titleEdgeInsets.top + titleEdgeInsets.bottom
        return sizeWithInsets
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked really well for me. The other solution didn't work as autolayout just took the intrinsic contentSize.

Comment: This works. But, setting `titleEdgeInsets` (or other insets) after that doesn't seem to work anymore

Comment: @Jeroen I updated my answer to demonstrate how to support `titleEdgeInsets` with this solution.

Answer (score 9):

`CGFloat` has a `leastNormalMagnitude` value that works nicely for this unfortunate UIKit hack.

```
someButton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: .leastNormalMagnitude, left: .leastNormalMagnitude, bottom: .leastNormalMagnitude, right: .leastNormalMagnitude)
someButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: .leastNormalMagnitude, left: .leastNormalMagnitude, bottom: .leastNormalMagnitude, right: .leastNormalMagnitude)
```

Zeroing out title-edge insets alone will only zero out the leading and trailing insets. Therefore, we have to also zero out content-edge insets to zero out the top and bottom.

And for convenience:

```
extension UIEdgeInsets {
    init(repeating value: CGFloat) {
        self.init(top: value, left: value, bottom: value, right: value)
    }

    static let leastNormalMagnitude = UIEdgeInsets(repeating: CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude)
}

someButton.titleEdgeInsets = .leastNormalMagnitude
someButton.contentEdgeInsets = .leastNormalMagnitude
```

Answer (score 8):

I had issue with extra padding around button's title in **iOS 15**, so I've solved the problem with following code:

```swift
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    detailsButton.configuration?.contentInsets = .zero

    // you could also keep padding that is more appropriate in your case
    detailsButton.configuration?.contentInsets = .init(top: 0, leading: 10,
                                                       bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
}
```

Also you could set style of UIButton in Attributes Inspector to `Default`. It'll make button's look same as it was before **iOS 15**

The [article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/button-configuration-in-ios-15/) that helped me to get it right.

Comment: This is the best solution imo

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's because of the deprecation of `contentEdgeInsets` and `titleEdgeInsets` in iOS 15, but neither setting `. contentEdgeInsets` nor `.titleEdgeInsets` did the trick for me on iOS 15.2. Please comment below if you are facing the same issue on iOS 15+.

Eventually I ended up setting `button.titleLabel` constraints manually to remove paddings.

```swift
// first disable auto generated constraints
button.titleLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// then pin titleLabel to the button
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.titleLabel!.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.leadingAnchor),
            button.titleLabel!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.trailingAnchor),
            button.titleLabel!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.topAnchor),
            button.titleLabel!.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution worked great for me (although I also had to set `button.titleLabel.textAlignment = .center`). But I think you're right that the deprecation of those properties makes the other answers outdated.

Answer (score 1):

A modern way for iOS 15+

```
let button = UIButton()
button.configuration = {
    var config = UIButton.Configuration.plain()
    config.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 0, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
    return config
}()
```

Comment: Please note that this general solution was posted nearly two years ago (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71882585/20287183).

Answer (score -1):

See if this works. Create the vertical constraints to the UIButton's titleLabel instead of the button itself.